# Tinymce inline editor appearing over the editable text and hiding the text with the editor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tinymce

Tinymce inline editor: The editor is appearing over the editable text and hiding the text but it should appear up to the text.

**This is my tinymce initialization.**

```
function initEditor(editableItemsClass) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: editableItemsClass,
        inline: true,
        menubar: false,
        highlight_on_focus: true,
        plugins: [
            'link', 'autolink',
        ],
        toolbar: [
            'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontsize | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignfull'
        ],
        valid_elements: 'p[style],strong,em,span[style],a[href],ul,ol,li',
        valid_styles: {
            '*': 'font-size,font-family,color,text-decoration,text-align'
        },
    });
}
```

**This is the html:**

```
<div>
   <h3 class="text-uppercase text-white m-0 text-center editable_textfields" style="letter-spacing: 2px;" id="home_event_name_1">We are getting married</h3>
</div>
```

[**This is my output image**](https://i.ibb.co/qrcVVDS/Screenshot-2023-05-31-015807.png)

Comment: It could be the css rules element